# How do I prevent vim from opening files with specified extensions on zsh?

Tags: zsh

Let's say I'm in a directory (using zsh) with these three files: `hello.c`, `hello.o`, and `hello.d`.

Now, if I type `vim he` and press TAB, I want zsh to, instead of giving me `vim hello.`, give me `vim hello.c` ignoring `hello.o` and `hello.d`.

I only want this to work for `vim`, and not some other command say `xxd`. Is there a way to achieve this in zsh?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to look up "autocompletion" in your zsh manual.  At least that's what it's called in bash.  https://linuxhint.com/setup-configure-autocomplete-zsh/

Comment: @kahlonel : I find your question a bit unclear: In the title, you are asking about _binary files_, but in the text of your question, you talk about _filenames ending in certain strings_. Please specify exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for pointing out. I matched the title with question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*:*:(vim|gvim):*' ignored-patterns '*.(o|d)'
```

The pieces:

- `compinit` - initializes the completion system.
- `zstyle` - configuration builtin that can be used to customize the completion system, among other things. Supplies key-value pairs for the code to operate with.
- `:completion ...` - the 'context' for this particular key-value pair.  It is a set of patterns at multiple levels.  Finding the context you need can be daunting, but for tab completion you can usually count on `completion` to be the first term and the program name to be fourth.
- `(vim|gvim)` - the program name. It's a glob-like pattern, so this   applies to `vim` or `gvim`.
- `ignored-patterns` - the style, i.e. the key that we are setting.
- `'*.(o|d)'` - the value for the key-value pair. Here, it's the glob pattern we want to ignore. Multiple parameters are accepted; `'*.o' '*.d'` would have the same effect.

Most of the styles are documented in the `zshmodules` man page, along with some documentation of the `zstyle` command.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It somehow doesn't work for `vi` command if I have `alias vi='nvim'` in my .zshrc. I had to add `setopt COMPLETE_ALIASES` for that to work. Thanks!